# Export encountered errors on following paths solve it these errors guys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, next.js

```
   Generating static pages (0/13)  [=   ]ReferenceError: location is not defined
    at g (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\.next\server\app\dashboard\notifications\page.js:1:5734)
    at nM (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:47419)
    at nM (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:61663)
    at nN (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64674)
    at nB (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:67657)
    at nF (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:66824)
    at nN (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64990)
    at nM (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:61233)
    at nN (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64674)
    at nI (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:46806)

Error occurred prerendering page "/dashboard/notifications". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

ReferenceError: location is not defined
    at g (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\.next\server\app\dashboard\notifications\page.js:1:5734)
    at nM (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:47419)
    at nM (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:61663)
    at nN (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64674)
    at nB (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:67657)
    at nF (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:66824)
    at nN (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64990)
    at nM (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:61233)
    at nN (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64674)
    at nI (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:46806)

 ⨯ useSearchParams() should be wrapped in a suspense boundary at page "/search". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/missing-suspense-with-csr-bailout

Error occurred prerendering page "/search". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

ReferenceError: location is not defined
    at g (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\.next\server\app\settings\edit-profile\page.js:6:463)
    at nM (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:47419)
    at nM (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:61663)
    at nN (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64674)
    at nB (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:67657)
    at nF (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:66824)
    at nN (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64990)
    at nM (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:61233)
    at nN (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64674)
    at nI (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:46806)

Error occurred prerendering page "/settings/edit-profile". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

ReferenceError: location is not defined
    at g (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\.next\server\app\settings\edit-profile\page.js:6:463)
    at nM (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:47419)
    at nM (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:61663)
    at nN (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64674)
    at nB (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:67657)
    at nF (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:66824)
    at nN (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64990)
    at nM (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:61233)
    at nN (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64674)
    at nI (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:46806)
ReferenceError: location is not defined
    at g (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\.next\server\app\settings\change-password\page.js:6:463)
    at nM (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:47419)
    at nM (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:61663)
    at nN (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64674)
    at nB (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:67657)
    at nF (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:66824)
    at nN (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64990)
    at nM (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:61233)
    at nN (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64674)
    at nI (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:46806)

Error occurred prerendering page "/settings/change-password". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

ReferenceError: location is not defined
    at g (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\.next\server\app\settings\change-password\page.js:6:463)
    at nM (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:47419)
    at nM (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:61663)
    at nN (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64674)
    at nB (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:67657)
    at nF (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:66824)
    at nN (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64990)
    at nM (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:61233)
    at nN (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64674)
    at nI (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:46806)
   Generating static pages (9/13)  [==  ]
ReferenceError: location is not defined
    at g (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\.next\server\app\dashboard\blogs\page.js:4:2242)
    at nM (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:47419)
    at nM (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:61663)
    at nN (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64674)
    at nB (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:67657)
    at nF (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:66824)
    at nN (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64990)
    at nM (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:61233)
    at nN (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64674)
    at nI (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:46806)

Error occurred prerendering page "/dashboard/blogs". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

ReferenceError: location is not defined
    at g (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\.next\server\app\dashboard\blogs\page.js:4:2242)
    at nM (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:47419)
    at nM (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:61663)
    at nN (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64674)
    at nB (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:67657)
    at nF (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:66824)
    at nN (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64990)
    at nM (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:61233)
    at nN (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:64674)
    at nI (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:46806)
ReferenceError: Element is not defined
    at 8391 (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\.next\server\chunks\447.js:10:508)
    at t (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:127)
    at 4731 (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\.next\server\app\editor\page.js:1:3616)
    at t (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:127)
    at F (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:94693)
    at C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:97108
    at W._fromJSON (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:97546)
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at N (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:94414)
    at t (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:100799)

Error occurred prerendering page "/editor". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

ReferenceError: Element is not defined
    at 8391 (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\.next\server\chunks\447.js:10:508)
    at t (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:127)
    at 4731 (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\.next\server\app\editor\page.js:1:3616)
    at t (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:1:127)
    at F (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:94693)
    at C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:97108
    at W._fromJSON (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:97546)
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at N (C:\Users\Ahmedka10\OneDrive\Desktop\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:94414)
 ✓ Generating static pages (13/13)

> Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /dashboard/blogs/page: /dashboard/blogs
        /dashboard/notifications/page: /dashboard/notifications
        /editor/page: /editor
        /search/page: /search
        /settings/change-password/page: /settings/change-password
        /settings/edit-profile/page: /settings/edit-profile
```

When I try to build the project, it shows this error..

Comment: please ask the entire question and provide some description rather than one liner.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The `location` object is available only in the browser's environment. If your code relies on `location` for server-side rendering in Next.js, you'll encounter errors during the build or prerendering phases because `location` is undefined in Node.js.

Wrap any code using `location` in a condition that checks if `window` or `location` is defined. This prevents the server from executing code that relies on these objects.

```js
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  // Safe to use window or location here
}
```

The `Element` object is part of the Web APIs provided by browsers and is not available in Node.js. This error usually occurs when your code or a library you use tries to access DOM elements during SSR.

For components or libraries using `Element` or other browser-specific APIs, consider importing them dynamically with `{ ssr: false }` to ensure they are only loaded client-side.

```js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const MyComponent = dynamic(
  () => import('../components/MyComponent'),
  { ssr: false }
);
```